# dataGrid doesn't update when item property has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I have almost identical thing set up with TextBoxes/ListBoxes and so on but it just doesn't seem to work with dataGrid..

So I have a view Index which contains dataGrid.

I created a IndexModel class which is as follows:

```
public class IndexModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Schedule> _schedules;

    public IndexModel(ObservableCollection<Schedule> schedules)
    {
        _schedules = schedules;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Schedule> Schedules
    {
        get { return _schedules; }
        set
        {
            _schedules = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in my IndexView I create IndexModel.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Schedule> _schedules;

    public Index(MainController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
        InitializeComponent();
        _schedules = controller.DatabaseController.GetSchedules() as ObservableCollection<Schedule>;

        DataContext = new IndexModel(_schedules);
        Log.Info($"UI Component {componentName} loaded succesfully",componentName, Source);
    }
```

I create the DataContext and bind it in XAML

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Schedules, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I even created a simple void.

```
Schedule selectedItem = (Schedule) dataGrid.SelectedItem;
selectedItem.Name = "Testing";
```

And it updates the ObservableCollection yet dataGrid doesn't update...

I looked through all the answers of stackoverflow and such but still could not fix my problem..

```
public partial class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Priorities Priority { get; set; }

    public virtual UpdaterObject Object { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ScheduleAction> ScheduleAction { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Schedule` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` when its `Name` property value changes.

Comment: Ah.. That makes sense. I had INotifyProperty changed instead of INotifyCollectionChanged. I will try it out with CollectionChanged and give an update soon

Comment: @Wkjjjj WHAT? What are you talking about?! There is basically never any reason to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Are you saying `Schedule` does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? If so, then the problem isn't what I thought it was at all.

Comment: @Wkjjjj Can you share the source for `Schedule`?

Comment: I updated my question. I guess I should implement INotifyProperty changed in my Schedule class instead of my model. I seem to understand what should I do now.

Though is there any difference if my Schedule model is from EntityFramework ? It's code first approach.

Comment: @Wkjjjj Go for it. When Entity Framework generates the classes for you, it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` automatically, so I wouldn't expect that to be a problem.

Comment: Though how do I implement OnPropertyChanged when all the propreties are just

string Name {get; set;} ?

I need to create private fields for those properties and do

Get { return _name }; Set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged() } ?

Comment: @Wkjjjj Yeah, you have to do the whole private field thing. Huge hassle if you don't [use snippets to create them](https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/viewmodel-property-snippets-c6/).

Answer (score 2):

According to your example, what should work is if you add or delete a Schedule dynamically in the collection.

But if you want to update a given Schedule from the UI like:

```
selectedItem.Name = "Testing";
```

What you want is to update a Shedule item itself, not the collection of Schedule.

In other words you need a viewModel for the Schedule if you want it to be edited in your view. Also you need to provide a data Template for the Shedule to let WPF know how it is suppose to render a Shedule.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I followed your advice and just made my property and mocked the data in it. then I edited in this way:
Schedules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1).Name == "Test";

I edited the item that was binded to ItemSource (checked through the debug collection 100% updated)

datagrid stays intact.

Comment: What does your DataTemplate looks like? http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html